# bash - problem with mv trying to move the asterisk

Tags: bash, shell-script, mv

I am trying to make a script that will move files with certain extensions or attributes to another program. All is well and good and the script works but `mv` keeps trying to move the statement files. For example here is part of the code:

```
dirs=($(find "$dir" -type d))
for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
for file in "$d"/*; do
    if [ -f "$file" ] && [ -x "$file" ]; then
        exefiles+=( "$file" )
        mv "$file" $bindir
    fi
done
    
for i in "${exefiles[@]}"; do
    echo "$i moved to $bindir" >> /home/$USER/$logname
done

for file in "$d"/lib*; do
    libfiles+=( "$file" )
    mv "$file" $libdir
done

for i in "${libfiles[@]}"; do
    echo "$i moved to $libdir" >> /home/$USER/$logname
done

for file in "$d"/*.c "$d"/*.cc "$d"/*.cpp "$d"/*.cxx; do
    srcfiles+=( "$file" )
    mv "$file" $srcdir
done
for i in "${srcfiles[@]}"; do
    echo "$i moved to $srcdir" >> /home/$USER/$logname
done

for file in "$d"/*.h "$d"/*.hxx; do
    incfiles+=( "$file" )
    mv "$file" $incdir
done

for i in "${incfiles[@]}"; do
    echo "$i moved to $incdir" >> /home/$USER/$logname
done
unset exefiles
unset libfiles
unset srcfiles
unset incfiles
cd "$d"
done
```

`mv` tries to move `"$d"/*` etc. itself and it prints that it cannot on the terminal and the logfile. Is there any way to prevent it, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this a matter of one or several of the patterns not matching any names? Does setting the `nullglob` shell option help?

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I didn't know about shell options before. Again thank you very much!

Comment: @Kusalananda may as well make that into an answer

Comment: See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: The `cd "$d"` is the problem. In this directory, the paths returned by `find` are no longer valid. I suspect your code works fine for the first directory found by find, and fails on the the second one.

Comment: @terdon That's only part of the answer though. The other part is shrinking the code down to a single loop with a `case` statement, called from `find`.